# Firefox 3.6.18 and IE Javascript insert rows into a table

Tags: javascript, firefox, html-table, cross-browser

I created a script that inserts some rows into a table. The script looks like this:

```
 for (j = 0; j < <?php echo $i; ?>; j++)
    {
        if ((utilizator[j]['nume'].toLowerCase().indexOf(nume.toLowerCase()) != -1) && (utilizator[j]['locatie'].toLowerCase().indexOf(locatie.toLowerCase()) != -1) && (utilizator[j]['varsta'].toLowerCase().indexOf(varsta.toLowerCase()) != -1) && (utilizator[j]['email'].toLowerCase().indexOf(email.toLowerCase()) != -1) && (utilizator[j]['telefon'].toLowerCase().indexOf(telefon.toLowerCase()) != -1))
        {
            var insertString = '<td>'+utilizator[j]['nume']+'</td>';
            insertString += '<td>'+utilizator[j]['locatie']+'</td>';
            insertString += '<td>'+utilizator[j]['varsta']+'</td>';
            insertString += '<td>'+utilizator[j]['email']+'</td>';
            insertString += '<td>'+utilizator[j]['telefon']+'</td>';
            insertString += '<td>'+utilizator[j]['punctaj']+'</td>';
            if (utilizator[j]['suspendat'] != 1)
            {
                insertString += '<td id="suspendareButon'+utilizator[j]['id']+'"><input type="button" value="Suspenda" onclick="suspendare(1, '+utilizator[j]['id']+')" /></td>';
            }
            else
            {
                insertString += '<td id="suspendareButon'+utilizator[j]['id']+'"><input type="button" value="Activeaza" onclick="suspendare(0, '+utilizator[j]['id']+')" /></td>';
            }
            var trTag = document.createElement("tr");
            trTag.innerHTML = insertString;
            document.getElementById("utilizatoriId").appendChild(trTag);
        }
    }
```

The scripts runs fine in Firefox 4.0+ (so I didn't see the problem) but one of my colleagues has Firefox 3.6.18 and it seems like the td tags are stripped. And I get something like `<tr>data data data data...</tr>` instead of `<tr></td>data</td><td>data</td>...</tr>`.

Any thoughts why this is happening?

Also in IE I get an error and nothing is displayed (the error is "object does not display this property or method", I can't exactly indicate the line because IE sucks at reporting...)

Comment: Why not use DOM consistently?

Comment: Yeah... that fixed the ff part. The IE still dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

You are not supposed to appendChild to a table, rather a tBody, but this will append to the table itself assuming I got all the syntax correct

```
  var util, trTag, tdTag, input, suspend, max = <?php echo $i; ?>;
  for (var j = 0; j < max; j++) {
    util = utilizator[j];
    if ((util['nume'].toLowerCase().indexOf(nume.toLowerCase()) != -1) &&
        (util['locatie'].toLowerCase().indexOf(locatie.toLowerCase()) != -1) && 
        (util['varsta'].toLowerCase().indexOf(varsta.toLowerCase()) != -1) && 
        (util['email'].toLowerCase().indexOf(email.toLowerCase()) != -1) && 
        (util['telefon'].toLowerCase().indexOf(telefon.toLowerCase()) != -1)) {
      trTag = document.getElementById("utilizatoriId").insertRow(-1);
      tdTag = trTag.insertCell(-1);
      tdTag.appendChild(document.createtextNode(util['nume']));
      tdTag = trTag.insertCell(-1);
      tdTag.appendChild(document.createtextNode(util['locatie']));
      tdTag = trTag.insertCell(-1);
      tdTag.appendChild(document.createtextNode(util['varsta']));
      tdTag = trTag.insertCell(-1);
      tdTag.appendChild(document.createtextNode(util['email']));
      tdTag = trTag.insertCell(-1);
      tdTag.appendChild(document.createtextNode(util['telefon']));
      tdTag = trTag.insertCell(-1);
      tdTag.appendChild(document.createtextNode(util['punctaj']));
      input = document.createElement("input");
      suspend = (util['suspendat'] != 1);
      input.type="button";
      input.id = "suspendareButon'+util['id'];
      input.value = (suspend)?"Suspenda":"Activeaza";
      input.onclick=function() {
        var suspend = this.value==="Suspenda"?1:0;
        var id = this.id.replace("suspendareButon","");
        suspendare(suspend,id);
      }  
    }
  }
```

Comment: I left my office 2 hours ago but i'll try it first thing in the morning and see if it works as expected (it looks fine 2 me). One little question... why can't I append a child to a table? (I'll do some research on my own of course but while I'm reading your post I keep wondering why).

Comment: Because some browsers want you to append to a tBody which they silently insert if there isn't one

Comment: Yes but "utilizatoriId" is a tBody not a table (I guess I forgot to mention that). Witch I used especially to avoid the confusion for browsers... table id is "utilizatoriTableId" with 2 tBody inside, one of them called utilizatoriId.

Comment: Yes you forgot to mention that :) In any case BE CONSISTENT and notice the much simpler function onclick

Comment: Working... not perfect but I'll take care of that. Ty.

Comment: @zozo - I would like to know about any error or syntax issues. Thanks

Comment: No syntax issues... but IE 7 still doesn't render the table. Hence the IE reporting sucks I can't really tell if is a problem with your script or some parts in mine. I'll investigate.

Comment: Make sure the doctype is correct. If you need, contact me on plungjan.name and send me a zip with the view-source so I can test in IE8 (in IE7 mode)

Comment: Is all ok. It was a problem with my code prior this part and the script was dieing there. Ty for help.

Answer (score 1):

Already Discussed Question : [Insert rows into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604281/javascript-insert-rows-into-table)

Check out article:

http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html

Comment: Many more SO entries, however this one deserved a little more attention since there are many things to improve